# Edit in ReactJS and Laravel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I'm trying to build Edit Page using Laravel and ReactJs but it just renders Edit form without any data in input field and when I click 'Update', it occurred an error: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Here's my code:

Example.js

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {posts: []};
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts').then(response => {this.setState({ posts: response.data });})
    }
    postRow(p){
        return (
            <tr key = {p.id}>
                <td>{p.title}</td><td>{p.description}</td><td><Link to={"edit/"+p.id}>Edit</Link></td><td></td>
            </tr>
        )
    }
    render() {
        const posts = this.state.posts.map(post => this.postRow(post));
        return (
                <div>
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr><th>Title</th><th>Description</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
                        <tbody>{ posts }</tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
        );
    }
```

Edit.js

```
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {postTitle: '', postDescription: ''};
        this.titleChange = this.titleChange.bind(this);
        this.descriptionChange = this.descriptionChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
       axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/${this.props.params.id}/edit')
                .then(response => {this.setState({postTitle: response.data.title,postDescription: response.data.description});
                })
        }
        handleSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            const post = {title: this.state.postTitle,description: this.state.postDescription}
            let uri = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/'+this.props.params.id;
            axios.patch(uri,post).then((response) ={this.props.history.push('/');});
        }
        titleChange(e){this.setState({postTitle: e.target.value})}
        descriptionChange(e){this.setState({postDescription: e.target.value})}
        render(){
            return(
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>Title: </label><input type="text" onChange={this.titleChange}/><br/>
                    <label>Description: </label><textarea onChange={this.descriptionChange}></textarea><br/>
                    <input type="submit" value="update"/>
                </form>
            )
        }
```

RoutePath.js

```
<BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
         <Route exact path='/' component={Example}/>
         <Route path="/edit/:id" component={Edit} />
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: cause `this.props.params` is undefined. It must be `this.props.match.params.id`

Comment: Thanks. It updated when I clicked "Update". However, when I click "Edit", the 
corresponding data still can't be shown in the input field, it's still empty

Comment: Cause you not set value to input field and textarea `<input type="text" onChange={this.titleChange} value={"some value"} />`